# PHP/JSON Skipping Over Information? Multiple Test Cases Provided

Tags: php, json, parsing

I've got another JSON / PHP question. I'll start off by posting a brief segment of the JSON, at least enough to convey my point:

```
 "results": [
    {
        "members": [
            {
                "side": "majority",
                "rank": 1,
                "title": "Chairman",
                "legislator": {
                    "bioguide_id": "T000464",
                    "birthday": "1956-08-21",
                    "chamber": "senate",
                    "contact_form": "http://www.tester.senate.gov/Contact/index.cfm",
                    "crp_id": "N00027605",
                    "district": null,
                    "facebook_id": "210573031664",
                    "fax": "202-224-8594",
                    "fec_ids": [
                        "S6MT00162"
                    ],
                    "first_name": "Jon",
                    "gender": "M",
                    "govtrack_id": "412244",
                    "icpsr_id": 40702,
                    "in_office": true,
                    "last_name": "Tester",
                    "lis_id": "S314",
                    "middle_name": null,
                    "name_suffix": null,
                    "nickname": null,
                    "office": "706 Hart Senate Office Building",
                    "party": "D",
                    "phone": "202-224-2644",
                    "senate_class": 1,
                    "state": "MT",
                    "state_name": "Montana",
                    "state_rank": "junior",
                    "term_end": "2019-01-03",
                    "term_start": "2013-01-03",
                    "thomas_id": "01829",
                    "title": "Sen",
                    "twitter_id": "testerpress",
                    "votesmart_id": 20928,
                    "website": "http://www.tester.senate.gov",
                    "youtube_id": "senatorjontester"
                }
            },
            {
                "side": "majority",
                "rank": 2,
                "title": null,
                "legislator": {
                    "bioguide_id": "P000590",
                    "birthday": "1963-01-10",
                    "chamber": "senate",
                    "contact_form": "http://www.pryor.senate.gov/public/index.cfm?p=ContactMe",
                    "crp_id": "N00013823",
                    "district": null,
                    "facebook_id": "9248638978",
                    "fax": "202-228-0908",
                    "fec_ids": [
                        "S0AR00028"
                    ],
                    "first_name": "Mark",
                    "gender": "M",
                    "govtrack_id": "300080",
                    "icpsr_id": 40301,
                    "in_office": true,
                    "last_name": "Pryor",
                    "lis_id": "S295",
                    "middle_name": null,
                    "name_suffix": null,
                    "nickname": null,
                    "office": "255 Dirksen Senate Office Building",
                    "party": "D",
                    "phone": "202-224-2353",
                    "senate_class": 2,
                    "state": "AR",
                    "state_name": "Arkansas",
                    "state_rank": "senior",
                    "term_end": "2015-01-03",
                    "term_start": "2009-01-06",
                    "thomas_id": "01701",
                    "title": "Sen",
                    "twitter_id": "senmarkpryor",
                    "votesmart_id": 35,
                    "website": "http://www.pryor.senate.gov",
                    "youtube_id": "senatorpryor"
                }
            },
```

Alright - the information I'm tryin to grab is the title of each legislator, as well as the bioguide_id. The code I'm using to parse the information is as follows:

```
 $url1 = 'http://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/committees?fields=members&apikey=XXXXXXXXXXX&per_page=20&page=1';
 $response1 = file_get_contents($url1);
 $key1 = json_decode($response1, true);


 foreach ($key1['results'] as $value){

$title_1 = $value['members'][0]['title'];

if($title_1 == NULL){
    $title_1 = "NULL";
}
echo $title_1 . '<br/>' . $value['members'][0]['legislator']['bioguide_id'] . '<br/>';

 }
```

However, the results from running the script are as follows:

```
 Chairman
 T000464
 Chairman
 M001170
 Chairman
 B001265
 Chairman
 L000261
 Chairman
 B000711
 Chairman
 K000384
 Chairman
 B001267
 Chairman
 C001070
 Chairman
 W000802
 Chairman
 M001176
 Chairman
 N000032
 Chairman
 K000367
 Chairman
 G000555
 NULL
 L000174
 Chairman
 H001069
 Chairman
 B001267
 Chairman
 D000607
 Vice Chairman
 B000243
 Chairman
 S000148
 Vice Chairman
 S000148
```

Upon first glance, I thought that things looked fishy because of the amount of Chairmen titles floating about (when there should be several NULL in between the Chairmen) and the second bioguide_id isn't the correct bioguide_id for the second position (Chairman & T000464 looks correct, but the next one shouldn't be Chairmen M001170, but NULL P000590). I've switched the $value['members'][0]... to $value['members'][1], and was able to get the second address, but the results weren't correct. Is there anything that anyone can see that would allow me to grab the correct information? From how I've worked with my other JSON files, it would seem that I'm not doing this dramatically incorrect. Thanks in advance (I know it was long).

Comment: This is really what SO created for...

Comment: Have you run the JSON data through a validator? e.g. http://jsonlint.com

Comment: From looking at the code, it looks like you need to iterate over the members, instead.

Comment: Can you update your post with the array instead of partial JSON?

Comment: You are always using member at index `0` is this intended?

Comment: Azad - this place really is my go-to resource after I've spent 3 or 4 days trying to solve my problems

Inspector-G - Of course my good sir! That's actually how I got the JSON results in the first place

MB34 - I can and will do that should the method below not function

Mike Brant - It was, because when I change the value, while I do get different data, it omits the first entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `foreach` is looping through the sets of results, not the sets of members.

Here is a working `foreach` that I have confirmed works:

```
foreach ($key1['results'][0]['members'] as $value) {
  $title_1 = $value['title'];
  if ($title_1 == NULL) {
    $title_1 = "NULL";
  }

  echo $title_1 . '<br/>' . $value['legislator']['bioguide_id'] . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: You are the man Ryan! Thank you so much - it's simple oversights like this that have hindered my coding for years. Thanks again